# Dynamic content for css before/after property

Tags: html, css

I have the following code which works for adding dynamic content into the :before and :after content attribute

```
<p data-before="World">Hello</p>

p:after {
    content: ' ' attr(data-before);
}
```

Is there a way I can add the content of an attribute from another element...

Something like this although this doesn't work!

```
<p data-before="World">Hello</p>
<div data-before="People"></div>

p:after {
    content: ' ' div:attr(data-before);
}
```

Comment: Not really AFAIK because you can't put HTML in a pseudo-element. JS solution I feel.

Comment: Try using some JavaScript or jQuery. It should be no problem for you to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use content from another element except from attributes of the original element.
If you don't want to use javascript you can [use url() inside css content](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_content_url) to dynamically load an image from your server instead.